# Change colour of line hr

Tags: html, css, navigation, hover

This is my website.. I need that line on the third section to be black.. I used the hr tag and styled it as white on css because the page after it i need it in a white colour? so how do i style them differently? Sorry, im new to html/css!

Please help!

http://opax.swin.edu.au/~9991042/DDM10001/brief_2/Amalfi%20Coast/www_root/

```
<div id="con2">

<div id="box3">
<span class="fontheading">RESEARCH, PLAN AND SAVE  </span> <br><hr /><br>
<span class="font1"> You&#39;ll collect all of <br>your favourite <br>
Amalfi activities <br>and attractions <br>in one place </span>
<br><br><span class="font2">Just sign up<br>for your free<br>account 
<a href="#">here</a></span>
 </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 hr { width:100%; height:1px; background: #fff }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<hr>` uses a `border`, not a `background-color`. In fact, it has a border on all sides. I usually override this by setting `border-width: 0px;` before setting the `border-bottom-*` properties

```
hr {
    border-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}
```

> how do i style them differently?

Append a class the `<hr>` tag you would like to change.

```
<hr class="white">
```

Then apply the css to that class only

```
hr.white {
    border-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}
```

You can change the amount of space an `<hr>` tag takes up vertically by changing the value of the `line-height` property.

```
hr.white {
    line-height: 1px;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add different classes for the different `hr` tags, for example: `<hr class='hr-black'/>` Then change the colors in CSS.

Comment: This is the way you should be doing it.  Different classes for each color `hr`.